# WPF. Нужно колонку заполнить ссылками

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

Имеется источник данных и DataGrid. Нужно заполнить последнюю колонку ссылками, ссылки будут однотипные примера somesite.ru/user?id=ID, где id берестся из ItemSource. Все никак с Binding разобраться не могу.

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="grid" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Geometria" FontSize="10" >
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Название" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Издательство" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Цена" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Просмотры" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Рейтинг" Width="100"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn>
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <!--тут ссылка-->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView NavigationStyle="Cell" FocusedRowChanged="TableView_FocusedRowChanged" AllowEditing="False">

            </dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А что сложного?

Создаёте конвертер:

```
class UriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var id = (string)value;
        return new Uri("http://somesite.ru/user?id=" + id);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Затем, положите его в ресурсы вашего окна:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:UriConverter x:Key="UriConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

И используйте для конвертации:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink
        NavigateUri="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}"
        RequestNavigate="OnRequestNavigate"><Run Text="{Binding NavigateUri,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Hyperlink}}"/></Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Подписка на `RequestNavigate` нужна для того, чтобы работали ссылки.

```
void OnRequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    var uri = e.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    Task.Run(() => Process.Start(uri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Вроде бы всё, должно работать.

Comment: То есть получается в UriConverter попадает значение из базы? Не подскажете хороший источник информации по Binding.

Comment: @Илья, в конвертер там попадает значение текущей строки текущего столбца. Откуда оно там берется в вашем случае - непонятно. Но, видимо, из базы :)

Comment: В `UriConverter` попадает то, что приходит после `Binding`. В вашем случае — id. По поводу что почитать, я бы посоветовал книги [отсюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105). Например, WPF Unleashed, Adam Nathan.

Answer (score 2):

А еще проще через форматирование

вот как выглядит биндинг

```
{Binding YourProperty, StringFormat='somesite.ru/user?id={0}'}
```

Ну а в вашем случае просто

```
{Binding StringFormat='somesite.ru/user?id={0}'}
```

Короче все то же самое, что написал VladD, только без конвертера

Comment: А если например в эту ячейку записывать значения из других ячеек грида той же строки

Comment: @Илья Для этого есть MultiBinding. Но в вашем случае я не уверен как лучше это сделать. Вы используете контролы DevExpress, а я их не очень то знаю :) Общий смысл в том, что значения ячеек нужно проставлять не через FieldName, а через TextBlock + binding, тогда вы сможете взять хоть все значения через мультибиндинг и так же вставить их в ссылку через StringFormat

Comment: @iRumba: Это работает, если Binding идёт к полю типа `string`. Но с `NavigateUri` типа `Uri` это [не сработает](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4782992/276994). Я пробовал тоже вначале :)

Comment: @VladD, так там по любому стринг. Это же таблица и данные скорее всего подтянуты из DataTable

Comment: @iRumba: Вроде бы `Hyperlink.RequestUri` не стринг. Вопрос не в источнике данных, а в том, _куда_ они биндятся. Попробуйте!

Comment: @VladD, да, вы правы. А вообще, это, конечно, ИМХО, но я бы все же делал это во вью модели. Без конвертера. Создал бы вычисляемый столбец (или свойство, если источником данных является коллекция из экземпляров класса)

Comment: @iRumba: Правильная мысль, кстати. Составление URI из id — не задача уровня UI. Может, напишете об этом в ответе? Это важное рассуждение.

Comment: @VladD, тут ваш ответ признан ответом, его и будут читать. Так что уж лучше в своем ответе это добавьте. Так эту мысль прочитает больше народу ;)

Comment: @iRumba: Идея по справедливости ваша, так что пусть лучше она будет у вас. А кто не читает альтернативные ответы, сам виноват.